# Does anyone think there is something wrong in The C Programming Language 2E Page29?

Tags: c

I am currently studying the well-known book for C - The C Programming Language, 2Ed. And when I trying the code in P.29, I think there is something wrong in the getline function:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

What if when the for loop ended, `i == lim-1` and `c == '\n'`? In this case, I think the array would be out of boundary, since `s[lim]` would be set to '\0'.

Does anyone think this is wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i<lim-1, can not make i=lim-1

Comment: @Ulterior: After a loop like `for (i=0; i<5; ++i);` runs, for example, i == 5.  The loop ends precisely because the condition part has become false.

Comment: @cHao I have discarded part of explanation, but current answers explain it in depth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator has "early-out" semantics.  This means that if `i == lim-1`, the rest of the condition is not executed - in particular, `c = getchar()` will not be called.

This means that in this case, `c` will have its value from the last iteration of the loop - and since the loop condition includes `c != '\n'`, this value can't be `'\n'` (or the loop would have exited last time around).

This is true as long as `lim` is greater than 1, which must be a precondition of the function (because calling the function with `lim` less than or equal to 1 would cause the uninitialised value of `c` to be read).

Comment: Oh, I have already learnt "short-circuit" rule, but I failed to link this to the problem. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

So, let's look at some cases:

If `lim == 0`:, then this will do undefined behavior. There's two places this will happen:

- We will execute no iterations of the for loop, giving `i == 0` and `c == undefined`.
- We then access `c` at `(c == '\n')`. It has no defined value yet, so it's undefined behavior.
- We then cause undefined behavior again by overflowing `s` with: `s[i] = '\0';`

What if `lim == 1`:

- The for loop will not be run, because the condition is not met.
- We will hit undefined behavior just like in `lim == 0` because `c` has no value.
- The last line will work fine.

What if `lim == 2`, and the input string is `"ab"`:

- The for loop will grab `'a'`, and place it into `s`.
- The for loop will exit on the next iteration, with the value of `c` still being `'a'`.
- The if conditional fails.
- The adding of the null character works fine.
- So `s == "a\0"`

What if `lim == 2` and the input string is `"a\n"` (Which is the case you're worried about):

- The for loop will grab `'a'`, and place it into `s`.
- The for loop will exit on the next iteration, with the value of `c` still being `'a'`.
- The if conditional fails.
- The adding of the null character works fine.
- So `s == "a\0"`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, your analysis is pretty clear. :)
But in the original code, lim is given a value of 1000. Anyway, thanks for your help~

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible for `i` to be `lim-1` and `c` to be `'\n'` at the same time.  If `i==lim-1`, then `i<lim-1` will be false, so it will never read the next character.  If `c` was `'\n'`, then the loop would have terminated before `i` got to be `lim-1`.

The loop is equivalent to this:

```
i=0;
while (i<lim-1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c==EOF) break;
    if (c=='\n') break;
    s[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop will continue until the condition  `i < lim-1` is true.When `i == lim - 1`, condition for loop becomes false and loop will terminate, and last element of array will stored in `s[lim -2]`.It will not go out of boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. - but in a different way.
There may have been is a problem.  Should the limit be reached `i==lim-1`, and c had the value `\n` from the previous loop - but this can not happen as the previous loop `c!='\n'` would have exited.

This *is* a problem with `lim <=1`.  The for loop exits, and `c` is not intiialized yet, thus undefined behavior with `if (c == '\n')`.  Could be fixed with

```
int c = 0;
```

As mentioned by others, there is an additional problem with `lim = 0` and `s[i] = '\0';`